# mapping arguments passed to function to local namespace using **kwargs?

Tags: python, function, namespaces, arguments, keyword-argument

If this is a duplicate question, my apologies in advance.. I would like to understand the **kwargs thing better in python and was actually hoping to be able to write a function that could handle unpacking and internally referencing the `key:value` pairs from passing in **kwargs arguments.

My little example is as follows:

`arguments = {'apple': 50, 'zoom': 'foo', 'bar': True}`

I would like to be able to reference the keys and values of the dictionary passed into the function without explicitly referring to them from within the function itself.

```
def test(**kwargs):

    if kwargs is not None:

        print(f'apple: {apple}')
        print(f'zoom:  {zoom}')
        print(f'bar: {bar}')
```

Calling the above via `test(**arguments)` of course fails, but is there a way to "unpack" the **kwargs into the local namespace within the function to accomplish what I am thinking?

One thing I've considered is to create a dictionary within the function and then use `exec()` to compile the key:value pairs into this namespace dictionary, but that seems a bit hairy.

Is there another way to assign local variables from **kwargs directly into a function?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I've also explored using `vars()` and have written the following:

```
def test(**kwargs):

    try:
        print(**vars())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, '\n\n')    
        print(vars())



    if kwargs is not None:

        try:

            print(f'apple: {apple}')
            print(f'zoom:  {zoom}')
            print(f'bar: {bar}')
        except:

            for k, v in kwargs.items():
                print(f'k: {k} : v: {v}')
```

With the following output:

```
'kwargs' is an invalid keyword argument for this function 


{'kwargs': {'apple': 50, 'zoom': 'foo', 'bar': True}, 'e':TypeError("'kwargs' is an invalid keyword argument for this function",)}
k: apple : v: 50
k: zoom : v: foo
k: bar : v: True
```

I notice that `print(**kwargs)` is trying to access "kwargs" as a named variable. I guess the question I am trying to resolve is if defining the function with default arguments, then passing in **kwargs would solve the issue? I can try this and see if it works and update..

**EDIT II**

This works..It looks like defining the function to have named defaults allowed me to reference those variables directly from **kwargs while not doing so entailed referencing the **kwargs dictionary and knowing the keys anyway.

```
arguments = {'apple': 50, 'zoom': 'foo', 'bar': True, 'baz': 99}


def test(apple = None, zoom = 'fee', bar = False, **kwargs):

    if kwargs is not None:

        try:

            print(f'apple: {apple}')
            print(f'zoom:  {zoom}')
            print(f'bar: {bar}')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e, '\n\n\n')

        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            print(f'k: {k} : v: {v}')

test(**arguments)
```

**EDIT III:** *update*

The following is the closest to what I had initially tried to convey and implement. A function that handles arbitrary user keyworded arguments and 
binds them to variables in a local namespace...

```
def test(**kwargs):            

   ns = {}

   args_string = ''

   for k, v in kwargs.items():

        print(f'k: {k}, v: {v}')

        try:
            args_string += str(k) + '=' + '{}'.format(int(v))+'\n'
        except:
            args_string += str(k) + '=' + '"{}"'.format(str(v))+'\n'


    exec(args_string, ns)   

    return {k:v for k, v in ns.items() if k in kwargs.keys() }
```

Running the following allows me access the variables, but I suspect this is not safe or "good" code.

`locals().update(test(**arguments))`

Comment: Why are you using `kwargs` at all? `kwargs` is for when you *don't* know what argument names you're interested in.\

Comment: To figure out what it does and why I may use it. I was mainly shooting for a quick way to pass dictionaries of variables to functions

Comment: You don't need to define your function with `kwargs` to do that. You can just do `def foo(apple, zoom, bar): ...` and call it as `foo(**your_dict)`.

Comment: Or, of course, you can just take the dict as a regular argument and index the dict the usual way.

Comment: This is what I'm going to go with now. I had created a function with a lot of arguments and was getting tired of defining the variables each time and was curious whether **kwargs was the answer, but I learned there are no shortcuts. Either way I have to "initialize" the variables to the function's namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kwargs` is a dict, so you can simply refer to the values within by their keys:

```
def test(**kwargs):
    if kwargs:
        print(f'apple: {kwargs.get("apple")}')
        print(f'zoom:  {kwargs.get("zoom")}')
        print(f'bar: {kwargs.get("bar")}')
```

Comment: I'd say this is the best answer for OP's use case